# One of my models causes the ...has no attribute '_meta' error when registered to the Admin interface.

Tags: python, django

My project consists of a 'User' model and a 'Timer' model.

My Timer model looks like this:

```
class UserTimer(models.Model):
    timer_user = models.ForeignKey('RegUser', related_name='user', verbose_name="User", null=True)
    timer_isPresent = models.BooleanField(_("User is present?"), default=False, blank=True)
    timer_enterTime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    timer_exitTime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Timer')

    def timerIn(self, user):
        ...
        return
```

After successfully registering the Users model, in the same way I am trying to register my timer model too:

```
class TimerAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    fieldsets = ['timer_isPresent']

admin.site.register(UserTimer, TimerAdmin)
```

But I get the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'` error.

I do realize it is most probably an issue with me using a `ForeignKey` in *Timer*, but I am not sure why or how can it be fixed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to register an inline admin class? Those are only for use as inlines in other admin classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets)

> fieldsets is a list of two-tuples, in which each two-tuple represents
>   a  on the admin form page. (A  is a “section” of
>   the form.)
>
> The two-tuples are in the format (name, field_options), where name is
>   a string representing the title of the fieldset and field_options is a
>   dictionary of information about the fieldset, including a list of
>   fields to be displayed in it.

so

```
fieldsets = ['timer_isPresent']
```

is not enough.

And, as Daniel Roseman has pointed out, your class should not inherit from StackedInline.

So to put it all together:

```
class TimerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
            (None, {
                'fields': ('timer_isPresent', )
            }),
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation cleared a few things for me. As for the inline, it was probably forgotten there while I was trying to fix the problem.